# transfer image files from Android to a Linux server using PHP

Tags: php, android, linux, api

I'm working on a project to transfer image files from Android to a Linux server using PHP.

In the Android application, it went smoothly, but the file was not created on the Linux server.

Here is my PHP code. Is there a problem?

```
 <?
    $file_path = "/home/jinwoo/Pictures/Logo/";
    $file_path = $file_path . basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)){
        echo "file upload success";
        echo $file_path;
    } else{
        echo"file upload fail";
    }
?>
```

In addition, I changed the permissions of all folders in the path where the file will be created to 777.

I'm sorry I used a translator because I am not good at English.

Answer (score 0):

`move_uploaded_file` is not able to do this work. In my project I have also face this problem. I found a solution and this works for me.

You need to do two things,

1. Tell your Android developer send that image in base64 file format.
2. In the PHP side you need to convert that base64 file to image file. Below I am give you PHP side code to convert base64 string to image file.

   `// $base64_string_data variable store the base64 data.
   $base64_string_data = substr($base64_string_data , 1+strrpos($base64_string_data , ','));
   // write the decoded file
   file_put_contents('MyImageFile.jpg', base64_decode($base64_string_data ));`

`MyImageFile.jpg` is the image file name. You can add your path here.

Note: In my project the app is working in Android and IOS also. In both the case its working fine.

Comment: Thanks to you, I have completed this part.